# Failed to create session exception in solace

Tags: solace

when trying to connect to solace to send notification, could not open the session to the solace URL. getting error in context.CreateSession(sessionProps, null, null))

please help to assist.

Exception thrown: Failed to create session
stackTrace:    at SolaceSystems.Solclient.Utils.Types.Utilities.GuardAgainstNotOk(ReturnCode returnCode, String message, Boolean includeSdkError, ISolLogger logger)
at SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging.Native.SessionImpl.InitSession(Session_CreateFuncInfoV2& sessionFuncInfo, IntPtr& opaqueSessionPtr)
at SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging.Native.SessionImpl..ctor(ContextImpl parentContext, SessionProperties sessionProps, EventHandler`1 messageEventHandler, EventHandler`1 sessionEventHandler)
at SolaceSystems.Solclient.Messaging.Native.ContextImpl.CreateSession(SessionProperties props, EventHandler`1 messageEventHandler, EventHandler`1 sessionEventHandler)
at Tutorial.TopicPublisher.Run(IContext context, String host) in C:\src\TopicPublisher\TopicPublisher.cs:line 142
at Tutorial.TopicPublisher.Main(String[] args) in C:\src\TopicPublisher\TopicPublisher.cs:line 228
Finished.

### below is the code block used:

```
`SessionProperties sessionProps = new SessionProperties()
{
        Host = host,
        VPNName = VPNName,
    UserName = UserName,
    Password = Password,
    ReconnectRetries = DefaultReconnectRetries,
    SSLClientCertificate = getCertificate(),
    SSLTrustStoreDir = Convert.ToString(SOLACE_SSL_TRUST_STORE_DIR),
    SSLValidateCertificate = true,
    SSLValidateCertificateDate = true,
    SSLExcludedProtocols = "",
    AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.CLIENT_CERTIFICATE,
}; // Connect to the Solace messaging router 
Console.WriteLine("Connecting as {0}@{1} on {2}...", UserName, VPNName, host);


using (ISession session = context.CreateSession(sessionProps, null, null))
{
    ReturnCode returnCode = session.Connect();
    if (returnCode == ReturnCode.SOLCLIENT_OK)
{
            Console.WriteLine("Session successfully connected.");
        PublishMessage(session);
    }
else
{
        Console.WriteLine("Error connecting, return code: {0}", returnCode);
}
}`
```

Comment: The error isn't very descriptive. Does the broker event log give you more info? Another common issue is the app not having the correct path or access to the truststore and client certificate. Please verify that is correct.

Comment: please guide where to check the broker event log. and trying to connect to solace from DEV machine where the certificate is deployed in truststore.